# How does setState() in Flutter work internally?

Tags: flutter

I have a Stateful widget in Flutter with a single variable, `count`.
Every time I press a button, the count is incremented and displayed on the screen.
I know I have to call `setState()` in order to update the UI with the new value.
Normally it is done as follows:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
     setState(() {
        count++;
     });
   }
```

My question is, why should I increment the variable `count` inside `setState()`?
It works perfectly well even if I do it outside:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    count++;
    setState(() {});
   }
```

So, why not just have a simpler method like `updateUI()` instead of `setState()`? Flutter internally can still call `setState()` whenever it wants, but for the outside world it can expose a more elegant API:

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: (){
      count++;
      updateUI();
    }
```

`updateUI()` can be called from anywhere when the screen needs repainting. `setState()` is more convoluted,  as it takes a function as argument. It is not clear what is supposed to be done inside that function.
What kind of operations are allowed/ disallowed inside `setState()`? I want to know the design thoughts that went into this.
For that matter, a *Stateless* widget also can have internal variables. Then why it cannot have an `updateUI()` method? Is it only for efficiency reasons?

Comment: "How does setState() in Flutter work internally? [...] What kind of operations are allowed/ disallowed inside setState()?" - see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/367f9ea16b/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L1140

Comment: Thanks, @pskink. This adds a bit more clarity. The only two conditions imposed on setState() are: 
1) setState() cannot be called after the widget has been disposed (obviously!) 
2) The wrapped function cannot be asynchronous. This is also understandable.
And there is the line

``final Object? result = fn() as dynamic;``

So this does allow the function to be null. But my original question remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flutter framework's `setState` method, as you've correctly pointed out, essentially schedules a rebuild of the widget when called. The main reason for using an anonymous function with `setState` is to ensure that the framework knows when you intend to update the state of the widget. Here are some key points to understand:

1. **Scheduling a Rebuild**: When you call `setState`, it tells Flutter to schedule a rebuild of the widget. This is necessary because Flutter is declarative, and you're describing how the UI should look based on the current state. When the state changes, you need to inform Flutter to re-render the widget with the updated state.
2. **Updating State**: The anonymous function inside `setState` is a convention that helps make your intent clear. While it's true that you can update the state directly before calling `setState`, it's considered a best practice to include the update within the callback. This is because it makes your code more readable and maintains a clear connection between the state change and the rebuild request.
3. **Conventions and Clarity**: Using an anonymous function with `setState` has become a convention in the Flutter community. It's a way to signal to other developers (and your future self) that you are intentionally changing the state and triggering a rebuild. It enhances code clarity and makes it easier for others to understand your code.
4. **Historical Reasons**: As this article mentioned https://iiro.dev/set-state/, this convention emerged from UX studies conducted by the Flutter team. They found that developers had an easier time understanding and correctly using `setState` with an anonymous callback than a direct `markNeedsBuild` method but where **also using the rebuild function a lot less with setState.**

In conclusion, while it's technically possible to update the state outside of the anonymous function in `setState`, it's considered best practice to follow the convention of updating the state within the callback. This convention enhances code readability, maintains clarity about your intent, and aligns with the way Flutter was designed to work. It's a convention that has evolved to make Flutter development more intuitive and less error-prone.

Regarding your idea of an `updateUI()` method:

While it's technically possible to create an `updateUI()` method to update the UI without using `setState()`, it goes against Flutter's design principles for the reasons mentioned above. Using `setState()` is the recommended and idiomatic way to handle UI updates in Flutter. By following this pattern, you ensure a clear and consistent approach to managing UI state throughout your application.

As for stateless widgets:

Stateless widgets are designed for cases where the UI doesn't change over time based on internal state. They are meant to be pure and stateless, meaning that once they are built, they don't change. Adding an `updateUI()` method to a stateless widget would contradict this design philosophy.

**Helpful Link: https://iiro.dev/set-state/**

Comment: This is wrong, you can refute a number of claims in this answer just by looking at setState's code. setState receiving a function is purely psychological. Flutter team initially tried the updateUI() idea, then they saw that people were placing it everywhere just in case. There is ZERO difference in having the variable change inside setState and before setState. It's a convention for programmers to tell each other and themselves "we're updating the ui because of these changes".

Comment: This article may help https://iiro.dev/set-state/#:~:text=So%20why%20do%20we%20have%20setState%20then%3F

Comment: You should really read the article: "So the whole setState API is just a mental trick. And it seems to work - apparently it lead into people building their widgets less often."

Comment: Thanks for the link. What the article says was logical.

Comment: Great article @GazihanAlankus. So mutating values inside the anonymous callback of the setState function is only used to avoid mistakes while writing code or to avoid forgetting calling setState after mutating the values.

Comment: I can see points (1) and (2) can be met with updateUI approach;  points (3) and (4) essential say "this is a convention for humans, and not necessarily for the computer".